# how can I calculate the integral by unit disc of $\dfrac{1}{\sin(z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

May I ask for help in calculating:

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{d z}{\sin z}\;?$$

I tried using residues, and I got the result $2\pi i$. But I'm not sure if it's true.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Maclauren series:

$$\sin z=z-\frac{z^3}6+\mathcal O(z^6)\implies\frac1{\sin z}=\frac1{z-\frac{z^3}6+\mathcal O(z^6)}=\frac1{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\mathcal O(z^5)\right)}=$$

$$\frac1z\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=\frac1z+\mathcal O(z)$$

So now you just have to the the integral of $\;\cfrac1z\;$ (as the rest is analytic and thus its integral equals zero), and you get $\;2\pi i\;$

Fill in details in the above...

Comment: Thank you veryy much! @DonAntonio

Comment: @Tota If the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted. Welcome to SE.

Comment: @MicahWindsor  because I'm new to this site,I'm not really sure how to do it... I see ✔️ next to the answer and  I pressed it. Is it ok, or I should do something more? Thank you!

Comment: @Tota, that's all you have to do :)